# Preventing SQL injections with PHP and Zend Framework - how?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-injection

I'm trying to defend the sign-in form on my page from SQL injections. On the serverside, I use Zend Framework (`Zend_Db`,`Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`), but its build-in injection prevention functions: `quote`, `quoteInto`, `quoteIdentifier` don't make their work well (as far as I know how to use them). Other ways like `mysql_real_escape_string`, `addslashes` do not seem to work at all...

This is what I'm trying to implement for the defense:

```
function prevent_from_sql_injection($str) {
    if(preg_match('/[\'"]/', $str))
     {die('attack1'); exit;  }// no quotes
elseif(preg_match('/[\/\\\\]/', $str))
     {die('attack2'); exit;  }// no slashes
elseif(preg_match('/(and|or|null|not)/i', $str))
     {die('attack3'); exit;  }// no sqli boolean keywords
elseif(preg_match('/(union|select|from|where)/i', $str))
     {die('attack4'); exit;  }// no sqli select keywords
elseif(preg_match('/(group|order|having|limit)/i', $str))
     {die('attack5'); exit;  }//  no sqli select keywords
elseif(preg_match('/(into|file|case|LOAD_FILE|DUMPFILE|char|schema|AES_DECRYPT|AES_ENCRYPT)/i', $str))
     {die('attack6'); exit;  }// no sqli operators
elseif(preg_match('/(--|#|\/\*)/', $str))
     {die('attack7'); exit; }// no sqli comments
elseif(preg_match('/(=|&|\|)/', $str))
     {die('attack8'); exit;  }// no boolean operators
elseif(preg_match('/(UNI\*\*ON|1 OR 1=1|1 AND 1=1|1 EXEC XP_)/', $str))
     {die('attack9'); exit; }
elseif(preg_match('/(&#x31;|&#x27;|&#x20;|&#x4F;|&#x52;|&#x3D;|&#49&#39&#32&#79&#82&#32&#39&#49&#39&#61&#39&#49|%31%27%20%4F%52%20%27%31%27%3D%27%31)/', $str))
     { die('attack10'); exit; }
elseif(preg_match('/(SELECT\s[\w\*\)\(\,\s]+\sFROM\s[\w]+)| (UPDATE\s[\w]+\sSET\s[\w\,\'\=]+)| (INSERT\sINTO\s[\d\w]+[\s\w\d\)\(\,]*\sVALUES\s\([\d\w\'\,\)]+)| (DELETE\sFROM\s[\d\w\'\=]+)/', $str))
     { die('attack11'); exit; } 
elseif(preg_match('/(script)|(&lt;)|(&gt;)|(%3c)|(%3e)|(SELECT) |(UPDATE) |(INSERT) |(DELETE)|(GRANT) |(REVOKE)|(UNION)|(&amp;lt;)|(&amp;gt;)/', $str))
     { die('attack12'); exit; } 
elseif(!preg_match('/^["a-zA-Z0-9\040]+$/', $str))
     { die('attack13'); exit; } 
else return $str;

}
```

As to test my results, I use Firefox extension [SQL Inject Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7597/) and it shows 14 more errors (sometimes 21 or 17 and I don't know why the results are different):

```
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: &#x31;&#x27;&#x20;&#x4F;&#x52;&#x20;&#x27;&#x31;&#x27;&#x3D;&#x27;&#x31;
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 UNI/**/ON SELECT ALL FROM WHERE
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: &#49&#39&#32&#79&#82&#32&#39&#49&#39&#61&#39&#49
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 OR 1=1
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1' OR '1'='1
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 EXEC XP_
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,3,4,5,6,name FROM sysObjects WHERE xtype = 'U' --
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: %31%27%20%4F%52%20%27%31%27%3D%27%31
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 AND 1=1
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1' OR '1'='1
Server Status Code: 302 Found
Tested value: 1 AND ASCII(LOWER(SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'), 1, 1))) > 116
```

So what is the best way to prevent all this SQL injection attacks? Using placeholders is good but it doesn't ok in some cases. Maybe this extension is wrong and I have a paranoia?

Comment: Define how the other options you mentioned "don't work well".

Comment: Have you considered some of these are just flase reports? Just because server returns 302 code,does not mean that injection succeeded.

Comment: Maybe you're right and this ext returns incorrect results. But how do then I test for sql injection?

Comment: Seeing such a ridiculous code snippets, I am always wondering, what if a site, where it have been posted, used the same "protection" method? How could you post a `elseif(preg_match('/(and|or|null|not)/i', $str))` string if there was such a checking here on so?

Comment: `but its build-in injection prevention functions: quote, quoteInto, quoteIdentifier don't make their work well` LOL. It works for everyone. So, the problem is somewhere else. Somewhere between the chair and the monitor...

Comment: `How could you post a elseif(preg_match('/(and|or|null|not)/i', $str)) string if there was such a checking here on so?` Where was it? Yes. It is just a ridiculous snippet and nobody says that it'll be used in production. `So, the problem is somewhere else. Somewhere between the chair and the monitor` So fat...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I strongly recommend the use of [Zend_DB](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html). It uses [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this.

> If an application exclusively uses
>   prepared statements, the developer can
>   be sure that no SQL injection will
>   occur (however, if other portions of
>   the query are being built up with
>   unescaped input, SQL injection is
>   still possible

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE reported_by = ? AND bug_status = ?',
    array('goofy', 'FIXED')
);

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

echo $rows[0]['bug_description'];
```

Comment: These params in array - are they quoted automatically or what?

Comment: Yes. That's what prepared statements are for. "The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically handles this." Please read the linked source for further information.

Comment: I agree with Benjamin, using Zend_Db takes out all the worry of prepared statements and I've not had any issues with it.

Comment: Sometimes prepared statements can allow SQL injections as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Vulnerabilities_inside_the_database_server

Comment: @FractalizeR "if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped input, SQL injection is still possible"

Comment: SQL injection is possible even if other portions of query are built with escaped input in MySQL. It was a bug with handling Unicode characters fixed in 5.0.22. Some servers still use this outdated release...

Comment: will it protect xss attack?

Comment: Please show, how to do the delete, update and more or give one reference links where it is properly written.

Answer (score 7):

Use prepared SQL statements instead of value escaping.

```
 $st = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x = ?");
 $st->execute($x);
```

Blacklisting a couple of SQL statements isn't a sensible approach. That Firefox extension is misleading and gave you the wrong impression.

Obviously you shouldn't start to accept random SQL commands as input. At most you use some request variables as query data. And prepared statements are sufficient to provide security for that case. Concatenating SQL commands and variables is an outdated practice (what that questionable Firefox extension seems to suggest.).

Comment: And that's exactly what Zend_Db offers.

Comment: What should I do with Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable ?

Comment: actually there is no problem with escaping if used properly

Answer (score -1):

Put this code into your header page.

```
function clean_header($string)
{
$string = trim($string);

// From RFC 822: “The field-body may be composed of any ASCII
// characters, except CR or LF.”
if (strpos($string, “\n“) !== false) {
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, “\n“));
}
if (strpos($string, “\r“) !== false) {
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, “\r“));
}

return $string;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If nighter works you can do this simple hack.

```
 public function sqlInjectionTest($str)
 {
    
    try{
         if (substr_count($str,"="))
        {
            throw new Exception("invalid input");

         }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Application error: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit;

    }
    
 }
```

It chckes in blind injection that if there is any '='? If its, there thows exeption.

to use it you can wite.

```
$this->sqlInjectionTest($parames_you_want_to_insert);
```